# AdalJs acquireToken fails with invalid state error

Tags: reactjs, adal.js

My adaljs code to fetch a token for a web api is suddenly failing. This has been working for months now. Since yesterday, I get the following error.

```
Invalid_state. state: 7ea40a81-5491-47a1-8ebc-89488acb673a|https://sykesenterprises.onmicrosoft.com/MyAPI
```

This happens when the acquireToken method is called.
I am using the example from https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-office-365-web-applications-react/ to use react with adaljs.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this out. If anyone else has the same issue, the answer was to just call adal.handleWindowCallback() at the entry point to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the sample you are referring to needs to be updated as per the latest version of Adal 1.0.16. I was able to fork the repo and submit a pull request to the owner to fix the invalid_state issue. Please refer to the link below to see the code changes:
https://github.com/waldekmastykarz/office-mygroups-react/pull/3/files

Comment: Thanks! Will try this once i get a chance.